# Is there a way to strip a csv string to 40 characters and remove anything after the last comma with regex?

Tags: java, regex

In a java project we have a limit of 40 characters to store some comma separated value string. We just need to display as many values as possible since it is for a report and not vital to display them all when there are more than 40 characters. Is it possible with regex to limit the string to 40 characters while removing the characters from the last comma?

Currently the code looks like this...

```
String csv = "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000";
String csvSub40 = csv.substring(0, 40);
String csvSub40LastComma = csvSub40.substring(0, csv.lastIndexOf(","));
//output is 11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666 as expected
```

I have tried a few things in regex, but can't figure out how to force it to find the last comma without breaking the cases where the string is shorter than 40 characters.

5/13 tests pass:

```
^(.{1,40})
```

9/13 tests pass (inverse):

```
^(.{1,40}),
```

I have a regex101 example with tests here: https://regex101.com/r/xC0dTB/1

**Edit:** To clarify for those not looking at the regex101 test cases here are all the test cases...

```
"11111" -> "11111"
"11111   " -> "11111"
"11111," -> "11111"
"11111,   " -> "11111"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555" -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555   " -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555," -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,   " -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666" -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666   " -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666," -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,   " -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000" -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000   " -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000," -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666"
"11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000,   " -> "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666"
```

Comment: something like this should work `/(.{1,40}),.*/`  Anchoring the last comma will ensure the longest (up to 40) will be matched.

Comment: It need not be regex, but `lastIndexOf(",", 40)` would fail several of the test cases. Also that is a reverse search and would be slow for huge strings while `indexOf(",", 40)` would start at the limit at least, but also fail.

Comment: True, but that would still fail multiple test cases (that I have in java).

Comment: @flip66 - If it doesn't necessarily be solved using regex, [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66556666/10819573) meets the requirement precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is what you're looking for:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\S{0,39}[^\\s,](?=(,|\\s+|$)))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(csv);
String csvSub40LastComma = matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : "";
```

There is no need to `trim`, `replaceAll` or do anything other than matching a regex.

You can play with this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/aBMnkx/1).

Comment: This appears to be failing several of the test cases.

this `11111,22222,33333,44444,55555`

is returning `11111,22222,33333,44444`

and `11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666`

is returning `11111,22222,33333,44444,55555`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do it using `String#substring`. Simply split the string on a comma and iterate the resulting array as per the specified length (e.g. `40` in your case). Finally, join the sub-array on a comma.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] csvArr = { "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000", "11111", "11111   ",
                "11111,", "11111,   ", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555   ",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,   ",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666   ",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,   ",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000   ",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000,",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000,   " };

        for (String csv : csvArr) {
            String[] values = csv.split(",");
            int i = 0, sum = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < values.length && sum + values[i].length() <= 40; i++, sum++) {
                sum += values[i].length();
            }
            String result = String.join(",", Arrays.copyOf(values, i)).trim();

            // Drop the last character if it's a comma
            int len = result.length();
            result = result.lastIndexOf(",") == len - 1 ? result.substring(0, len - 1) : result;

            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666
11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666
```

Answer (score 0):

This should cover all the tests.  Regex needs little help (from another regex) to trim end of line spaces and dangling comma.

```
 String[] tests = {
                "11111", "11111",
                "11111   ", "11111",
                "11111,", "11111",
                "11111,   ", "11111",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555   ", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,   ", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666   ", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,   ", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000   ", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000,", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666",
                "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,00000,   ", "11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666"};

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((.{1,40})(,|$))");

        for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i += 2) {
            String trimmed = tests[i].replaceAll(",?\\s*$", "");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(trimmed);

            if (m.find()) {    
                String g = m.group(2);

                if (!(tests[i + 1].equals(g))) {
                    System.out.println("Failed: \"" + g + "\"");         
                }
            } else {         
                System.out.println("Not Found: \"" + tests[i] + "\"");
            }
    }
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/OnCQIU/1

That doesn't work for the other cases like just 11111

Comment: @flip66 let me know whether the updated regex works for all your test cases.

Comment: This is failing similar test cases to the other answer.

this `11111,22222,33333,44444,55555`

is returning `11111,22222,33333,44444`

and `11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666`

is returning `11111,22222,33333,44444,55555`